# Grep for windows

Tags: cmd, grep, findstr

`Old.txt` contains

```
apple
orange
banana
```

And `New.txt` contains

```
apple
orange
banana
grape
lemon
```

I can access new contents which are added to `New.txt` using `grep` command.

```
grep -Fxvf Old.txt New.txt > difference.txt
```

Now, `difference.txt` contains

```
grape
lemon
```

In Windows, I have tried

```
findstr /rvc:Old.txt New.txt > difference.txt
```

to find the difference but it append contents of `Old.txt` too. How can I write equivalent command in Windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `DOS` [`findstr`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) with the following flags:-

```
/v   : Prints only lines that do not contain a match.
/g: file   : Gets search strings from the specified file.
```

The command would be something like:-

```
C:\Users\dude\Desktop>findstr /v /g:Old.txt New.txt >difference.txt
```

Now checking the file output using the `type` command; equivalent to `cat` in `Linux`, we see :-

```
C:\Users\dude\Desktop>type difference.txt
grape
lemon
```

Comment: Inian Thanks it works. I got  a new problem. It doesn't work when Old.txt is empty and New.txt contains some content

Comment: @MusieMeressa: The file after the `/g:` flag must have some entries, As you can see in the above example, it sees each line from 'Old.txt' and performs a invert search on the other file. So only the non-empty file must be under `/g:` flag for this solution to work. So, can you try `findstr /v /g:New.txt old.txt`, now that `New.txt` does have entries, this will work!

Comment: It doesn't work when one of the file is empty even if I change the order. Thanks anyhow .

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are restricted from installing anything on your PC, considering installing ports of *nix-like tools such as [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) and continue to use grep.

Comment: u r right, I am not allowed to install anything on the PC

Comment: Or use the Linux shell that recently was added to Windows 10 (assuming that's the OS)